# Inheritance within a Python Package between modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I am trying to implement inheritance between two classes inside two modules within a package. My current directory structure looks like the following:

```
bin/
  main.py 

packages/
  __init__.py
  modA.py
  modB.py

tests/
  testA.py
  testB.py
```

In main I am calling functions from the modules located in packages. 
In modA there is a class "class A".
In modB there is a class "class B".

Class B needs access to class variables from class A so I want class B to inherit from class A.

Inside of my __ init __.py I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from .modA import class A
from .modB import class B
```

Inside of the modB.py I have.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import packages

class classB(packages.classA):

    def __init__ (self):
        self.name   = str()
```

However I get the following error when I try to run the code.

```
AttributeError: module 'packages' has no attribute 'classA'
```

When I remove the inheritance and instead just create an instance of class A inside the **init** method of class B there is no problem with the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import packages

class classB():

    def __init__ (self):
        self.a = packages.classA()
```

The above runs fine so why cant it be recognised when implementing inheritance relationship?

**NOTE**
I have also tried to remove everything from the **init**.py file and implement the the imports directly within the modA and modB files themselves but this results in a different import error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from .modA import classA

class classB(classA):

    def __init__ (self):
        self.name   = str()
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'classA' from 'packages.modA' (../pacakages/modA.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what variables you are trying to access as it can either be class variables or instance variables. For each the structure of the classes may change.

if you want to access classA, *instance variables* you have to send them to classB in order to access it. Your classes will look something like:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'My'
        self.y = 'Class'

    def Amethod(self):
        self.concatenation = self.x + self.y
        return self.concatenation



class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, class_a):
        self.xB = class_a.x
        self.yB = class_a.y
```

If you are trying to access *class variables* you can access them without sending object form classA to classB(you will remove 'class_a' from classB constructor)

```
class ClassA(object):
    x = 'Something'
    y = 'Something else'
    def __init__(self):
        ClassA.x = 'My'
        ClassA.y = 'Class'

    def Amethod(self):
        ClassA.concatenation = ClassA.x + ClassA.y
        return ClassA.concatenation



class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        xB =  ClassA.x
        yB =  ClassA.y
```

building an object using class variables will be like:

```
objectB = ClassB()
objectB.Amethod()
```

building an object using instance variables will be like:

```
objectA = ClassA()
objectB = ClassB(objectA)
```

Also, in your **init**.py you wrote:

```
form .modA import class A
```

I do not know if that is unintentional but to me it seems you have an extra space as your class names are classA, classB

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi the init.py part was just a typo when I was changing the names of classes for this example. I want to access a class variable from classA in classB. What you have above will work fine if classA and classB are in the same file, the problem I am having is they are in two different modules and cannot seem to implement inheritance relationship because of this. Your second implementation is what I am trying to do, in classB I can call something like print(classA.x) and get the value of the classA variable x.

Comment: If you are using Python 2 it will be 'from packages.modA import classA', if you are using Python 3 it will be 'from .modA import ClassA'. Try this and let me know if this resolves your issue. Also, I do not know if you have more files and are importing from one another, it may be cause by something called "Cyclic import" - write the importing statement in your modB class not in __init__, leave __init__ empty, it is just to show that it's okay to import within your directory.

Comment: The problem was to do with Cyclic imports yes, I was importing modB in modA also as I was creating instances of classB from classA however I was also still importing modA in modB. I took this approach of only importing modB in modA when it was needed https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/ would you recommend this way it fixes the problem or have you another solution?

Comment: Depends on the scope of your applications. My personal recommendation is to avoid circular imports at all costs and reduce circular dependency. If you can fix your problem by calling classes and methods only when necessary you can do it if your program doesn't have a large scope. Depending on how many classes you are connecting to one another your solution may be the best for your application